# Unzip split Zip or/and multi zip in c++ or c or Objective-C

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, c, unzip

I want to Unzip a multi zip files or a split files directly in my application in iPad.
For this i have minizip a framework in langage C (thats work for a simple .zip file).

So my question is how Unzip a file like .z01, .z02 or/and a file .zip.001, .zip.002 in one of this language C, C++ or/and Objective-C (if possible an example of how make this)?
I try (in Objective-C) too take data of all files and assemble in one file that doesn't worked, so an other response possible is to explain how a split of zip is made (just data cut or somethings else)?

Thanks in advance for your consideration

Comment: You say if you create a temp file that is the result of concatenating all the pieces, that file does not unzip. So try doing this concatenation on your Mac, add it to your app, and (as an experiment) see if you can unzip that file. If you can, then you are not concatenating the file properly in your app. If not, then there is something wrong with the file parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally,

when you split a zip file in multi files like zip.001 zip.002 etc... you just cut the data of source file.

So for unzip this type of files just take data of all files and concat in one file, after this just unzip this new file with framework minizip and in Objective-C use the code project ZipArchive (that use minizip) in google source code.

P.S : Thanks to David H for his help.

Comment: Hi, can you give more information on how to concat the split-zip files into one? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, if you split like i say in .zip.001, .zip.002, etc... you just need to create a new file like name.zip and just convert your file .zip.001 into NSData and put this NSData to your new file name.zip made that for all 00X and you have your real zip. If your file was split with extension .z01 i don't really know how made that.